# nodejs createWriteStream - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, createwritestream

I have this code in my node cli script

```
const dateTime = new Date();
const logFile = path.resolve(__dirname, `${dateTime.toLocaleDateString('it-IT')}.txt`);
const appLog = fs.createWriteStream(logFile, {flags: 'a+'});

console.log(chalk`{magenta.bold Log file created in ${appLog}}`);

//Logging events
            if( event.type === 'message' ){
                getInfo(eventID, (err, user) => {
                    if( err ){
                        appLog.write(err);
                        appLog.end();
                        return console.log(chalk.red.bold(err));
                    }
                    console.log(chalk`{yellow.bold New message:}\n${event.body}`); 
                    appLog.write(`${username}:`);
                    appLog.write(event.body);
                });
            }
```

What I want to do is to create a log file when the script is launched and then when an event occur log the event to it on a new line. The problem is that the script will not run and I get an error because the file not exist.
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dev/Desktop/node-fr/18/2/2021.txt'`
I've used the `a+` flag that is supposed to create the file if it's not exist. What I'm doing worng?

Answer (score 1):

use flags 'w', which is the default flags, instead.

```
const dateTime = new Date();
const logFile = path.resolve(__dirname, `./${dateTime.toLocaleDateString('it-IT')}.txt`);
const appLog = fs.createWriteStream(logFile, {flags: 'w'});

console.log(chalk`{magenta.bold Log file created in ${appLog}}`);

//Logging events
            if( event.type === 'message' ){
                getInfo(eventID, (err, user) => {
                    if( err ){
                        appLog.write(err);
                        appLog.end();
                        return console.log(chalk.red.bold(err));
                    }
                    console.log(chalk`{yellow.bold New message:}\n${event.body}`); 
                    appLog.write(`${username}:`);
                    appLog.write(event.body);
                });
            }
```

Comment: the 'w' flag will create a new file for each lineI need to add to the log, I want to create the file and then append to it each new line